# jQuery .live() and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

hey all,
Im stumped.
I have the following code..works fine in all browsers except IE (shocking...I know)

```
 $('#lbAvailableResources option').live('click', function() {
    if($('#ulResourcesAssigned').text() === 'No resources assigned')
         $('#ulResourcesAssigned').text('');

    //create a new listitem that will be added to the list of assigned resources
    $('<li>').val($(this).val()).text($(this).text()).appendTo('#ulResourcesAssigned'); });
```

the listbox (#lbAvailableResources) is loaded via an ajax call when the page loads.

Ive also tried the following:
1. I tried the delegate() method...no dice
2. I tried livequery...no dice

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just a side note... is .val() really applicable outside of form elements? e.g. I've only ever used it on `input`, `select`, `textarea` & `button` - I don't think I've ever seen it used on an `LI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no events on the `option` element in IE.

The `select` element may be implemented as an OS widget, in which case you can forget getting any fine-grained mouse events on sub-parts of the control.

The `change` event on `select` is the only cross-browser-compatible way to be informed of a change of option. Note that keyboard navigation may also fire this event.

If what you want is a control that pops up a list of options and lets you add content to another element whenever any option is clicked, the `select` element is ill-suited. Try instead a pop-up `div` containing buttons.

Comment: Bobince....you were right on the money. I modified the code to bind as follows:   $('#lbAvailableResources').bind('change', function() {}) and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help. Where did you learn this? can you point me to a site or did you learn it by suffering through?

Comment: Well historically it hasn't been reliable to treat the `<option>` as an entity in its own right, for scripting or styling. It's only newer browsers that put some effort into treating them as first-class elements. FWIW the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't list a `click` event (though it does list a bunch of other generic events that also don't fire on options).

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your code and see if there are any places where you are using console.log(), or ending an array of values with a "," . These are two other instances that IE will not work while some other browsers will.

```
$('#lbAvailableResources option').die();

$('#lbAvailableResources option').live('click', function(event) {

  if ($('#ulResourcesAssigned').text() == 'No resources assigned') { //is absolute equality needed here?
    $('#ulResourcesAssigned').text('');
  } //i always use brackets, it makes for more readable code

  //create a new list item that will be added to the list of assigned resources
  $("li").val($(this).val()).text($(this).text()).appendTo('#ulResourcesAssigned'); //the "" are not needed
});
```

Give the above a try, I have no idea whether or not it works